# Is it correct to state that basic primitive recursive functions are in fact combinators?

Tags: lambda-calculus, computability-theory

Is it correct saying that the Zero, Successor and Projection functions can be seen as combinators?

Comment: This question would probably have been more appropriate at math.stackexchange.com, since while it’s a good question, it’s not really reasearch-level.

Comment: sorry, I didn't know about math.stackexchange.com; I found out about it a minute ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if I'm right in assuming you mean to ask whether these can be construed without free variables in the lambda calculus.  (If my assumption is wrong, I apologize; your question is rather terse.)  You can see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding), for instance, how the "Church numerals" (Zero among them, of course) can be introduced, along with Successor and various other primitive recursive functions.

Comment: Your assumption is right. 

My question was terse because I'm very new to the subject, and it's still quite a lot confused in my head; I'm trying to understand by the help of something I think I'm more confident with (computability theory).

Thank you!